# Создать скрипт для вывода данных из массива

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
$cars = [
['name' => 'Такси 1', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
['name' => 'Такси 2', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
['name' => 'Такси 3', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
['name' => 'Такси 4', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
['name' => 'Такси 5', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
];
```

Есть переменная:

```
$passenger = rand(0, 1000);
```

Как написать скрипт который будет выводить:
<Название машины>, строит на <км, где стоит машина> км, до пассажира <км до пассажира> км (<занят/свободен>)</ - едет это такси>

Например:

"Такси 1, стоит на 15 км, до пассажира 3 км (занят)" 
"Такси 2, стоит на 0 км, до пассажира 12 км (свободен) - едет это такси"
"Такси 3, стоит на 300 км, до пассажира 288 км (свободен)"

Comment: А ваши попытки?

Comment: Я разобрался как вывести какое такси, сколько км, сколько км осталось. Не могу разобраться как вывести занят/свободен

Comment: `if ($array['isFree']) {} else {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не сдали курсовую по `PHP`?

```php
<?php
$cars = [
['name' => 'Такси 1', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
['name' => 'Такси 2', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
['name' => 'Такси 3', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
['name' => 'Такси 4', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
['name' => 'Такси 5', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
];

$passenger = rand(0, 1000);
//эмилируем самую ближайшую машину, но занятую, такую наш алгоритм выбрать не должен
//несмотря на то.что она ближе всех
$cars[] = ['name' => 'Такси 6', 'position' => $passenger, 'isFree' => false];

function getNearestCarName( $cars, $passenger ) {
    $result = "";
    foreach( $cars as $car ) {
         $distance = abs( $car['position'] - $passenger );
         if ( $car['isFree'] && ( !isset( $distance_min ) || $distance < $distance_min ) ) {
             $distance_min = $distance;
             $result = $car['name'];
         }
    }
    return $result;
}

$nearestCarName = getNearestCarName( $cars, $passenger );

foreach( $cars as $car ) {
  echo $car['name']." стоит на ".$car['position']." км, до пассажира ".abs( $car['position'] - $passenger )." км (".( $car['isFree'] ? "свободен" : "занят").")".( $car['name'] == $nearestCarName ? " - едет эта машина" : "")."\n";

}
```

Comment: Ага, завалил. Но все равно спасибо